# Java Method returning null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream

i want to read an input stream and my problem is that this method always returns null although there is no Exception output and the String output (see below) is correctly..
Does anybody have an idea how i can fix that problem?

```
private ArrayList<String> getPlayer(String name){

    try{
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes;
        InputStream in = openFileInput(name);
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();

        while((numBytes = in.read(b)) != 0){
            content.add(new String(b, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));
            String string = new String(b, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(string);     //StringOutput 
        }
        return content;


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());   //ExceptionOutput 
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Exception, that is thrown and makes the application stop:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: auldo.trainersoccer, PID: 7733
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at auldo.trainersoccer.ManageSpielerActivity$1.onItemClick(ManageSpielerActivity.java:60)
                                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: by debugging and checking what exception is thrown. if it wasn't from the catch block, it wouldn't return null since context is instantiated

Comment: yea where's the problem?

Comment: How are we going to tell you the problem if you haven't supplied any Stacktrace or information... Could you instead print a stacktrace and post that here.

Comment: There is nothing in your file?

Comment: @domiauli pass `openFileInput` method code

Comment: @476rick that is not the problem...`InputStream in = openFileInput(name);` may be null

Comment: I'd recommend moving `content` outside the entire try-catch, then you at least can return an empty list when an error occurs.

Comment: What @cricket_007 said, there is no reason to be initialising an `ArrayList` in a try-catch unless you only want it to be instantiated on some condition, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your while loop condition

`while((numBytes = in.read(b)) != 0){`

Change this to:

`while((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0){`

There is a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException that occurs when you use the `!=` condition because when you reach end of the file, the `in.read` method returns a **-1**

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because of an *StringIndexOutOfRangeException*.
You are not checking if the end of the stream has been reached. As the Java doc states the end of the stream is indicated by a return value of **-1**. So you should do `((numBytes = in.read(b) != -1)`.

Comment: Your method throws an Exception due to the fact that you don't check against -1. As a result it jumps into the catch block which returns null. This causes in the further context to throw another NullPointerException